# Mostrar resultado JSON en navegador

Tags: php

Ejecuto una prueba para consumir una api en postman y me devuelve un token, hasta ahí todo bien. Pero cuando copio el código para que me lo muestre en mi web con un simple index.php, me sale la página en blanco:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://ws.madaboutinfo.es/api/Alojamientos/Tipos',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
"Username": "turismomadrid",
"Password": "cwmg?rY2c"
}',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6InR1cmlzbW9tYWRyaWQiLCJuYmYiOjE2NjUwNjcxMDYsImV4cCI6MTY2NTA2ODkwNiwiaWF0IjoxNjY1MDY3MTA2LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3dzLm1hZGFib3V0aW5mby5lcyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3MubWFkYWJvdXRpbmZvLmVzIn0.-XcOl8HnJrkWv_XtFO4b5mi6jY0YJFuthkndkOstJd0',
'Content-Type: application/json'
),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

[image: postman]

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: y por si acaso como entras al index.php?

Comment: creo un archivo index.php con el codigo anterior y me responde pagina en blanco , cabe decir que lo lanzo desde localhost usando waamp

Comment: cambia `echo $response;` por `var_dump($response)` y agrega en tu publicacion cual es el resultado

Comment: la respuesta es : bool(false)

Comment: tambien recivo false en una prueba que hice ... de que manera lo haces en postman puedes subir una captura de todo lo que configuras y haces?

Comment: si claro , pero para volver a postear en esta pregunta como deberia actuar para no liarme o liarla. solo me da la opcion de añadir comentarios

Comment: dale en editar y despues CTRL+V cuando tenas copiada la imagen ... o captura

Comment: creo estar casi seguro que tiene que ver con el CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER: debe ser generado desde el php no copiado de postman y usado en el php despues ...

Comment: hechale un ojo a esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40582472/17161735

Comment: buuf ahi ya me he perdido , si pudieras encaminarme a algun post o enlace para crear lo que me comentas , seria un gran ayuda

Comment: ok voy a probar , si lo consigo edito solucion , muchisimas gracias

Comment: dale cuenta con mi apoyo... cualquier cosa seguimos aqui

Comment: vale lo voy a estudiar pero pq en este editor https://paiza.io/projects/lBxsOkLUslXKk4moq7GENg    con el codigo copiado de postman si que da la respuesta JSON?

Comment: es posible que si acepte el request desde esa url y no desde tu local ...

Comment: Si tienes acceso al código fuente de https://ws.madaboutinfo.es/api/Alojamientos/Tipos que verifique en su monitor de errores si hay algo que no se está cumpliendo o sino esta disponible esa función. Envía el resultado que te sale en el POSTMAN para saber si esta disponible tu recurso.

Comment: despues de varias pruebas, el mismo codigo de postman , funciona si lo alojo en un server normal o por ejemplo en un proyecto ddev , pero desde wamp nada de nada. Opciones ?? montar el proyecto en ddev pero lo complicado es que esto ira complementado en un joomla.. O buscar pq en wamp no funciona o directamente usarlo en un server subido a la red

Comment: prueba usar DOCKER XD

Comment: bueno lo he conseguido con xampp. muchas gracias por todo